# Chef cookbook template REGEX to match

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a template file

```
#fileName: test.properties.erb
<% if @env == 'STAGING' && node['hostname'] =~ /^staging/ %>
somekey=node['hostname']
<% else %>
somekey=defaultNode
<% end %>
```

My Recipe is as follows

```
template ("test.properties") do
  source 'test.properties.erb'
  variables(
    env: "STAGING"
  )
end
```

I wanted to perform && operation along with REGEX check

when i use the below in the erb file it works with &&

```
<% if @env = 'STAGING' && node['hostname'].include?('staging-01') %>
...
```

I wanted to apply a regex and check if the hostname starts with string `staging`
say I have `staging-01`, `staging-02` and apply on both

Comment: Is `node['hostname']` a String ?

Comment: yes that is a string, returns the hostname

Comment: So this file that has the logic is an erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be simple Ruby string matching expression

So i made the change to expression `node['hostname'].match(/staging*/)` and this evaluated the cookbook successfully.

```
#fileName: test.properties.erb
<% if @env == 'STAGING' && node['hostname'].match(/staging*/) %>
somekey=node['hostname']
<% else %>
somekey=defaultNode
<% end %>
```

Comment: This link https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/06/ruby-regex/ helped